# 'cider-jack-in' run clojure instead leiningen without a clojure project

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen, cider

I tried to execute 'cider-jack-in' from emacs without a Clojure project that I simply want to run Clojure REPL. But I've found that cider is trying to run `/usr/local/bin/clojure` instead `/usr/local/bin/lein` which don't refer my `profiles.clj` for Leiningen settings. It's normally work with `lein` when I try with a Clojure project.

I'm wondering there is any reason for that even there's no problem when I tried `lein repl` without a Clojure project in terminal which I've expected Cider to do so, and a way for setting up to run Leiningen through Cider without a Clojure project.

I'll appreciate for any comments on this.

Answer (score 2):

On CIDER 0.18 (the current stable version) you need to set `cider-jack-in-default` to a symbol, not a string (e.g. `'lein`).

```
(define-obsolete-variable-alias 'cider-default-repl-command 'cider-jack-in-default)
(defcustom cider-jack-in-default (if (executable-find "clojure") 'clojure-cli 'lein)
  "The default tool to use when doing `cider-jack-in' outside a project.
This value will only be consulted when no identifying file types, i.e.
project.clj for leiningen or build.boot for boot, could be found.

As the Clojure CLI is bundled with Clojure itself, it's the default.
In the absence of the Clojure CLI (e.g. on Windows), we fallback
to Leiningen."
  :type '(choice (const 'lein)
                 (const 'boot)
                 (const 'clojure-cli)
                 (const 'shadow-cljs)
                 (const 'gradle))
  :group 'cider
  :safe #'symbolp
  :package-version '(cider . "0.9.0"))
```

The old variable did take a string, that's true. Without seeing the complete stacktrace I can't be certain what's exactly going wrong for you. Generally it's best to bring up such problems on CIDER's issue tracker.

In case someone's wondering why now CIDER uses `clojure-cli` instead of `lein` for a projectless REPLs - our thinking was that the Clojure CLI is the only tool we can assume that every Clojure user would have, so it made for a safer default.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I've leaved the issue on CIDER's issue tracker: https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/issues/2470

Answer (score 1):

Try: `(setq cider-jack-in-default 'lein)`

Comment: Thanks @dpassen. 

I tried with your suggestion and also tried another suggestion like: `(setq cider-default-repl-command "lein")`
But the problem in any of cases is that the REPL is beeing stuck when I try to evaluate any code on it or working normaly after printing a long error message.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find the conditions reproducing each of the issues so far, But somehow I've got huge hint from you.

Comment: The error is: 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No method in multimethod 'op-handler' for dispatch value: null
    ...
    cider.nrepl.middleware.util.error_handling$eval2592$fn__2593.invoke (error_handling.clj:162)
    ...`

Comment: Unfortunately, this goes well beyond my knowledge base. If no one here knows, I suggest making an issue against [cider](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider).